# template parameter inference for std pair

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, `X x1{{100,5.55}, "abc"}` fails to compile ("candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T1'").
I believe that this is because, template deduction does not consider implicit conversions, so the compiler does not treat the first argument as a std::pair.

Is there any way to make the `X x1{{100,5.55}, "abc"}` syntax work?  I want to avoid explicit use of std::pair in the argument, because I am refactoring a large code base where this expression is used in many places.
(In the current code, the constructor is not templated, because it uses std::variant to create an omnibus class that handles multiple types with implicit constructors for int, double, std::string, etc.  I am trying to replace this class with a templated constructor that preserves the underlying data types, to improve type safety.)

```
#include <utility>

struct X
{
template <class T1, class T2> X(std::pair<T1,T2>, const char*){}
};

int main()
{  
  X x{std::pair{100,5.55}, "abc"};  // OK
//  X x1{{100,5.55}, "abc"};        // Compile error
}
```

Comment: my guess would be that `{100, 5.55}` is deduced as an `std::initializer_list`, and that `std::pair` must not have a corresponding constructor.

Comment: @Mansoor I don't think it is being deduced at all. To my knowledge this is a [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Comment: @Mansoor You're wrong. OP already mentioned the correct reason for the code not working which is that **implicit conversion is not considered in template argument deduction**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect solution, but if I am understanding your constraints well enough, it is not a big deal if new code needs to explicitly use `std::pair{}`, but old code has to remain compatible.

What about introducing a simple compatibility `struct` and (ab)using aggregate initialization to provide a constructor overload?

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    template <class T1, class T2> X(std::pair<T1,T2>, const char*)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }

    struct LegacyPair
    {
        int a;
        double b;
    };

    X(LegacyPair p, const char* text) :
        X(std::pair{p.a, p.b}, text)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    X x1{std::pair{100,5.55}, "abc"};
    X x2{{100,5.55}, "abc"};
    //X x3{{3.14,5}, "abc"}; // error
    X x4{std::pair{3.14,5}, "abc"};
}
```

This outputs:

- `X::X(std::pair<_T1, _T2>, const char*) [with T1 = int; T2 = double]` for `x1`
- `X::X(std::pair<_T1, _T2>, const char*) [with T1 = int; T2 = double]` for `x2`
- An error for `x3` (better than accidentally constructing a `std::pair<int, double>`). Because `{}` is aggregate initialization here, implicit conversion is not allowed, so this overload gets discarded. Which is good!
- `X::X(std::pair<_T1, _T2>, const char*) [with T1 = double; T2 = int]` for `x4`

Comment: The original use wraps multiple types into a single class via std::variant (with implicit constructors for ints, doubles, strings, etc).  I have edited the question to clarify this point.